# why are initial CSS styles not visible on DOM element.style field?

Tags: javascript, html, css, stylesheet, getcomputedstyle

OK I have full expectation of going down in flames for asking something stupid (or at least duplicate), but in the attached snippet, why do I have to use `window.getComputedStyle` to access styles applied by CSS? I was under the impression that the `.style` field would at least reflect those styles initially applied by CSS, and/or manually changed since then.

If not, what are the exact rules governing which properties are reflected (and when) in an element's `.style` field?

```js
setTimeout(() => {
    console.log("the bckg color:", reddish.style.backgroundColor);
    console.log("the width:", reddish.style.width);
    console.log("from a computed style:", window.getComputedStyle(reddish).backgroundColor);
    console.log("from a computed style:", window.getComputedStyle(reddish).width);
}, 100);
```

```css
#reddish {
    background-color: #fa5;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<html>
    <body>
        <div id="reddish"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> The **HTMLElement.style** property is not useful for completely
>   learning about the styles applied on the element, since it represents
>   only the CSS declarations **set in the element's inline style
>   attribute**, not those that come from style rules elsewhere, such as
>   style rules in the  section, or external style sheets. To get
>   the values of all CSS properties for an element you should use
>   **Window.getComputedStyle()** instead.
>
> Via- [MDN Web Docs | Getting Style
>   Information](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/style#Getting_style_information)

---

**HTMLElement.style:**

The [HTMLElement.style](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/style) property is used to ***get*** as well as ***set*** the **inline style** of an element.

```js
console.log(document.getElementById("para").style.fontSize); // will work since the "font-size" property is set inline
console.log(document.getElementById("para").style.color); // will not work since the "color" property is not set inline
```

```css
#para {color: rgb(34, 34, 34);}
```

```html
<p id="para" style="font-size: 20px;">Hello</p>
```

---

**Window.getComputedStyle():**

The [getComputedStyle()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle) method however, returns an object containing the values of all CSS properties of an element, after applying active stylesheets and resolving any basic computation those values may contain thus returning the css properties from both inline style declarations as well as from external style-sheets.

```js
console.log(window.getComputedStyle(document.getElementById("para")).fontSize); // will work
console.log(window.getComputedStyle(document.getElementById("para")).color); // will work
```

```css
#para {
  color: rgb(34, 34, 34);
}
```

```html
<p id="para" style="font-size: 20px;">Hello</p>
```

Comment: You should probably have quoted [this paragraph](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/style#Getting_style_information) instead. Ps:  quote blocks are supported in the editor.

Comment: @Kaiido Indeed. Let me update the answer. Thanks for the heads up man.

Answer (score 6):

`HTMLElement.style` is for the [*inline* style of an element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/style). It does not take into account CSS whatsoever. This is basically just directly setting or getting a property on the element object.

```
<div style="color: red;">Hello</div>
```

`Window.getComputedStyle()` takes into account [inline styles *and* CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle), after resolving cascading, inheritance, etc. It's basically the "final" actual style value used to render the element on the page.

```
// CSS
#blue-text {
  color: blue !important;
}

// HTML
<div style="color: red;" id="blue-text">Hello</div>

// JS
const myElement = document.querySelector("#blue-text");
myElement.style.color; // "red" because that's the inline style
window.getComputedStyle(myElement).color; // "rgb(0, 0, 255)" because CSS !important overrides inline style
```

Comment: OK, so basically, I can trust `HTMLElement.style` if and only if either either: (a) I am accessing a style property that was defined inline (and not overridden by some `!important` CSS declaration), or (b) I am accessing a style property that was previously set via `element.style.property = ...`?

Comment: Basically yeah.

Comment: @Labrador that depends what you expect it to mean. You can't **ever** trust Element.style to return the applied value of a CSS property. It can very well be overridden by an `!important` rule somewhere else, or even just be some value with no real meaning like `"auto"`.

Comment: ...except that using `element.style.property = ...` still does not override an `!important` CSS style, apparently. So the rule is really: using `HMTLElement.style` is like editing the inline `style` attribute of the element, nothing more. (@Kaiido our comments crossed. Thanks.)