# JS skips if statement on first event

Tags: javascript, html, css

The HiddenUI as well as the HiddenElements are supposed to be displayed when pressing Enter.

That works but **only on the second time I'm pressing "Enter".** The first time the if-statement in my toggleHiddenElements function skips the the first if statement and jumps straight to else. (checked with debugger).

But **it does work as intended the second time I press enter.**

```
/*toggle view hiddenUI and hidden elements*/

function toggleHiddenElements() {
  let HiddenUI = document.getElementById("hiddenUI");
  let HiddenElements = document.getElementsByClassName("deactivated");
  if (HiddenUI.style.display == "none") { /*jumps to else the first time I press Enter
    HiddenUI.style.display = "block";
    for (let i = 0; i < HiddenElements.length; i++) {
      HiddenElements[i].style.display = "block";
    }
  } else {
    HiddenUI.style.display = "none";
    for (let j = 0; j < HiddenElements.length; j++) {
      HiddenElements[j].style.display = "none";

    }
  }
}


/* EventListener for "Enter" Keybind */

document.addEventListener("keydown", (e) => {
  if (e.code == "Enter") {
    e.preventDefault();
    toggleHiddenElements();
  }
});
```

Full code can be found [here](https://jsfiddle.net/Lzj0ck5x/)

Comment: Please add a [mcve] (with the focus on _minimal_) that shows the actual problem _in the question itself_

Comment: The `style` object attached to an element node will not show you styles driven by CSS (or by simple default).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [why are initial CSS styles not visible on DOM element .style field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54321532/why-are-initial-css-styles-not-visible-on-dom-element-style-field)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [HTMLElement.style](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/style) property only represents the CSS declarations set in the element's inline style attribute, so the first time toggleHiddenElements() runs, `HiddenUI.style.display` is an empty string.

To fix your code, you can use [window.getComputedStyle()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle) to initially get the styles you set in CSS:

```
if (window.getComputedStyle(HiddenUI).display == "none") {
  HiddenUI.style.display = "block";
  for (let i = 0; i < HiddenElements.length; i++) {
    HiddenElements[i].style.display = "block";
  }
} else {
  HiddenUI.style.display = "none";
  for (let j = 0; j < HiddenElements.length; j++) {
    HiddenElements[j].style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

More info:
[why are initial CSS styles not visible on DOM element .style field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54321532/why-are-initial-css-styles-not-visible-on-dom-element-style-field)